# Prevent duplicate SQL entries and insert data to SQLite in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, pdo

On submit/refresh the same predefined data in my array is added. How do i stop it being added more than once. I'd like to get rid of the data in my array if possible and just catch user input from the form which then is submitted to the array but i'm not sure how. Also how can i get my form to submit to my SQLite database, i think i need to add an INSERT INTO statement somewhere. Any help would be nice as i need this finished soon. :(

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Input</title>
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('sqlite:mydb.sqlite3');
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $dbh->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
             name VARCHAR(30),
             gender VARCHAR(30),
             age INTEGER)"
             );

    $data = array( //Want to remove this prewritten data and store user input instead.
            array('name' => 'Daniel', 'gender' => 'Male', 'age' => '21')
            );

    $insert = "INSERT INTO test (name, gender, age)
           VALUES (:name, :gender, :age)";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($insert);


foreach ($data as $m) {
    $name = $m['name'];
    $gender = $m['gender'];
    $age = $m['age'];
    $stmt->bindParam('name', $name);
    $stmt->bindParam('gender', $gender);
    $stmt->bindParam('age', $age);

    $stmt->execute();

}
    $result = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM test');

    $dbh = null;

}
    catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();
}       

?> 

<div id="wrapper">

   <div class="banner1">
        <h2>Input</h2>
   </div>

<form id="form" method="post">
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name[0]"/> <br>
    Gender:<br>
    <input type="text" name="gender[0]"/> <br>
    Age:<br>
    <input type="number" name="age[0]" min="1" max="99"/> <br>

    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Input">
    </form>

</div>

<div id="results">

    <div class="banner2">
            <h2>Results</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="data">
        <?php
            unset($_POST['submit']);
            $data=$_POST;

            foreach ($result as $row) {
            echo $row['name']  . " ";
            echo $row['gender'] . " " ;
            echo $row['age']  . "<br>" . " ";
            }

        ?> 
    </div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot so you can grasp an idea of the form and how i'd like it to work. The results section is just generated from the array so i can see what is being inputted, but i'd like the input form to send data to the SQLite database that i have created/connected to above. Thank you.
[image: Screenshot of Form:]

Comment: Just add a query before the insert ... `SELECT * FROM test WHERE name=?` etc. and if the query has results, skip the `insert`.

Comment: *"On submit/refresh the same predefined data in my array is added. How do i stop it being added more than once."* - Add a header to redirect on successful query, and also set a UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: *"Also how can i get my form to submit to my SQLite database, i think i need to add an INSERT INTO statement somewhere."* - Isn't that what you're doing here `$insert = "INSERT INTO test (name, gender, age)`?

Comment: In reply to 'Isn't that what you're doing here $insert = "INSERT INTO test (name, gender, age)?' Yeah but it doesn't successfuly insert the form results into the database.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to test if Post exists
And second, check if the user already exist

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    // check for existing user
    // Save
}
```